# Cosa significa "scazzimma"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Non è per il fatto di rubare, balbetta Diamante. Allora è peggio ancora. Ti pisci sotto, **scazzimma** – conclude Rocco, risalendo in bicicletta.

Non ho trovato il termine "scazzimma" su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare cosa significa? Immagino si tratti di un vocabolo di origine regionale.

Comment: Nel libro [*La metafonia napoletana: evoluzione e funzionamento sincronico*](https://books.google.es/books?id=PRVv6P3ct2wC&pg=PA268&lpg=PA268&dq=scazzimma&source=bl&ots=oOTJExA05_&sig=ACfU3U3LZFN3_ebz1TZUJLyVbfCkAqzHzw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4nL341obhAhUn1uAKHQIBAQYQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=scazzimma&f=false) di Michela Russo si trova «*scazzimma* 'cispa'».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In questo articolo dell’[Accademia della Crusca riguardante la *cazzimma*](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/cos-cazzimma) viene menzionata anche la scazzimma come secrezione cisposa, detta anche cispa.

Per il Sabatini Coletti la [cispa](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/cispa.shtml) è:

> **cispa** [cì-spa] s.f.
>
> •   Secreto della congiuntiva che si raggruma sul bordo e agli angoli
>   delle palpebre, spec. durante il sonno o negli stati patologici
>   dell'occhio
>
> •   sec. XV

In [questo dizionario dialettale](https://m.dialettando.com/dizionario/detail/?id=33253) si trova la seguente definizione:

> TRADUZIONE DELLA PAROLA ITALIANA "CACCOLA, CISPA"
>
> **Campania**: caccola, cispa: scazzimma 
> **Puglia**: caccola, cispa, cerume:
>   cacche

Nel contesto da te citato il termine scazzimma viene usato da Rocco per apostrofare, insultare Diamante in quanto è titubante, ha paura di rubare.

Comment: Ho trovato un'altra fonte che menziona questo stesso significato (vedi il mio commento). Se vuoi puoi includerla nella risposta.

Comment: Tuttavia, nel brano della domanda penso che il termine sia usato come un insulto con la connotazione di qualcosa di piccolo (Diamante è un bambino) ma alla stesso tempo che meriti profondo disprezzo.

Comment: @Charo infatti nel dizionario dialettale viene indicato come sinonimo di scazzimma anche caccola, un termine sicuramente dispregiativo utilizzato per dire che Diamante è una cosa da niente.

Comment: E cos'è una "caccola"?

Comment: @Charo Da Treccani: il muco che si rapprende entro le narici; anche cispa degli occhi.

Comment: Dove appare questo nel vocabolario Traccani? Ho visto che c'è còccola1 e còccola2, ma questa accezione non l'ho trovata.

Comment: [Da Treccani per caccola](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/caccola/) vedi il significato 2.

Comment: Grazie, @abarisone! Il problema era che avevo scritto coccola invece di caccola.